# как правильно воспользоватся методом .reshape()

Tags: python

Пытаюсь разобраться но не получается корректно воспользоватся функцией reshape()
Есть звуковой сигнал который переведен в вектор (1990000, )
Что необходимо сделать:
Разделите сигнал на равные части (длину каждой части возьмите равной 1000) и соберите из них "датасет", который будет представлять из себя двухмерный массив - "матрицу", в которой каждая часть сигнала длины 1000 находится в отдельной строке).

То есть первая часть содержит первые 1000 чисел сигнала и находится в первой строке матрицы, вторая часть следующие 1000 чисел сигнала и находится во второй строке матрицы и так далее.

На текущий момент разделил

```
X_mono = mono_sound.reshape((2, 995, 1000))
print(X_mono.shape)
(2, 995, 1000)
```

Но как разделить по строкам?

Comment: у вас сейчас так и есть (2, 995, 1000) - два массива по 995 строк в каждой 1000 отсчетов

Comment: А зачем вы делаете трёхмерный массив? Делайте двухмерный. reshape(1990,1000).

Comment: вообще-то зависит от данных - если на входе что-то типа wave,  то решейпать надо, мне кажется (-1, 1000, 2) - там по два отсчета в стерео?